# Anki: How do you display double-braces?

Tags: anki

In Anki, I would like to be able to create cards for learning some templating languages that also use the double-brace syntax.

So for example, on the front side of the card I want to ***display*** this:
`{{myAngularVariable}}`

But Anki has its own templating system which uses the same syntax.  When I view the card, Anki delivers an error message like this:
`{unknown field myAngularVariable}`

Is there a way (or Anki syntax) to quickly display double braces, ***without getting into the html***?

Answer (score 1):

I ended up solving this with an [AutoHotKey](https://autohotkey.com/) snippet to replace all braces with a utf-8 character that looks about the same.  Here's my AHK script:

```
#IfWinActive,Add
:*:{{::｛｛
:*:}}::｝｝
#IfWinActive  ; turns off context sensitivity

#IfWinActive,Edit Current
:*:{{::｛｛
:*:}}::｝｝
#IfWinActive  ; turns off context sensitivity

#IfWinActive,Browser \([0-9]+ card(s?) shown
:*:{{::｛｛
:*:}}::｝｝
#IfWinActive  ; turns off context sensitivity
```

I'd love to know of a more straight-forward approach though.

Comment: escaping with \ will not work, but as soon as the two braces are separated by anything, the field is not recognized by Anki. So I would try a very thin whitespace character, like &thinsp; or U+200B (&#8203;) , U+200C (=&#8204; = &#x200c;  =  &zwnj;) .